# Create subpages for each folder in current directory with PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to create download pages for pictures taken with a photo booth. I'd like to have for each event an own page, where the images can be viewed and downloaded.

To avoid double code I'd like to create a download page template (a single PHP file), which scans its directory and produces an own page for every folder (containing the JPGs and a ZIP file). Each page should get a different URL. The HTML should be mainly the same, just the displayed and downloadable files differ. How to achieve this?

I'm aware of the `scandir()` function but allready lost how to produce an empty page with an own path for every folder.

Comment: Are tot planning to create a separate php file in each folder? Better to have 1 php file that can read any folder. Use a DirectoryIterator to get the files.

Comment: I want to have a single PHP file, which creates a download page for each folder in the current directory. I edited the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED answer:

From testing it looks like scandir will scan the names of folders and files in the specified directory but nothing really beyond that. You'll need to do this in a couple of parts. Part 1, get all the directories available in the main folder leaving out actual files with extensions:

```
<?php

$dir    = 'path/to/current/directory/with/other/image/folders';
$files = scandir($dir); // get all files and folder names for this directory

$filecontents = file_get_contents('file_that_generates_gallery_and_download_links.php');

// Loop through files and figure out which ones are directories
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
    if ($path_parts['extension'] === null) {
        file_put_contents( $dir . $path_parts['filename'] . '/filename.php', $filecontents);
    }
}
?>
```

That takes care of creating a unique path for each directory/gallery. The new file is created in the same directory as the images. The next part is creating the "file_that_generates_gallery_and_download_links.php" referenced in the code above:

```
<?php

$dir    = 'path/to/current/directory/with/images';
$files = scandir($dir);
$domain = 'https://yoursite.com'; // I hard-coded this value but do what makes since for your site's setup
$gallery = ''; // Used to hold the HTML for displaying the images and download links

// Loop through array of image files to create a "gallery", create an image tag for showing the image and an HTML download link beneath the image. Using download on the <a> tag tells the browser you want the user to download the file instead of linking to it.
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $gallery .= '<div><img src="'.$domain . $file.'" alt=""><br><a href="'.$domain . $file.'" download>Download Image</a></div>';
}
?>
<div class="container">
    <?php echo $gallery; ?>
</div>
```

This gave me the following output as a gallery:

[image]

Based on this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => file12345.png
    [1] => file12345.png
    [2] => file12345.png
    [3] => file12345.png
    [4] => file12345.png
    [5] => file12345.png
    [6] => file12345.png
    [7] => file12345.png
    [8] => file12345.png
    [9] => file12345.png
    [10] => file12345.png
    [11] => file12345.png
    [12] => ..
    [13] => .
)
```

I of course styled the gallery with CSS and used classes to demonstrate how the code can build the image view and links dynamically. The download links actually work too, the image is downloaded right then and there.

I hope this is better than the previous response.